# Illegal string offset and not showing the form fields in a contact-script.php

Tags: javascript, php

I get:

"Warning: Illegal string offset 'select' in C:\sites\travel-division\mail_com\contact-script.php on line 75

````
    /* Select */
    
    /* This is line 75 */ if(is_array($acf_type['select'])) {  ?>
    <div><select <?php echo $acf_attributes_html; ?> name="<?php echo $acf_key.$addMultipleSign; ?>" id="<?php echo $acf_key; ?>">
    
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    
    <?php
    foreach($acf_form_fields[$acf_key]['type']['select'] as $acf_value) {
        
    if($addMultipleSign == '') {
    $acf_selected = ($_POST[$acf_key] == $acf_value) ? 'selected' : '';
    } else {
    $acf_selected = (in_array($acf_value, $_POST[$acf_key])) ? 'selected' : '';
    }
    
    echo '<option '.$acf_selected.'>'.$acf_value.'</option>'."\n"; }
    ?>
    </select></div><br />
    <?php
    }
    
    /* End of Select */```

Please shed some wisdom on this issue.
Thank you,
Buzz
````

Comment: What does ```<?php echo $acf_attributes_html; ?>``` echo out?

Comment: Could you share the complete script, what happens before line 75?

Comment: How is this related to `javascript`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)